# Initializing a new string

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

this is a beginner question.
I needed a new string variable today, so I did something like this:

```
NSString* newString = nil;
if(something)
newString = @"a value";
else
newString = @"different value";
```

and it worked just fine. Still, I do know a little about memory allocation, and I feared this might cause problems somehow, so I changed in the end the code to:

```
NSString* newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
if(something) ...
```

Is it a bad practice what I previously did? 
I know some variables get allocated automatically, so you don't need to call alloc for them, but wouldn't initializing them as nil work just as well?
I'm sorry if this question sounds silly, I came to objective-c from php and my knowledge about memory management is close to.. nil

[**edit**]
This is not a question about nil vs @"";
My question is if it's ok to simply use a `NSString = something` (nil, @"", @"a value") and if, in general, it's ok to do this for objects.
For example, instead of doing a `NSRandomObject = [[NSRandomObject* alloc] init];` I can simply do `NSRandomObject = aValue;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both branches of the `if` assign a value to `newString`, assignment prior to `if` has no effect.

Deciding on whether or not to initialize a string to `nil` vs. an empty string is an application-level decision, often centered around the distinction between "the string is not there" and "the string is there, but it is empty".

Comment: Of course it has no effect, that was the idea :D I can't use NSString* theString = @"something"; inside the if, and then theString inside else, because it will tell me it wasn't properly declared. That's why I used an empty init before the if/else structure.

Comment: @BogdanBucur in cases when you override the value on both sides of the `if` (i.e. unconditionally) it is better to initialize to `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

A string that's prefixed by an `@` is stored in the program code only once, and is then used as a static address. There's no need to worry about their memory.

In fact, using `stringWithFormat` takes up a lot more memory than simply `@"string"`

Fun fact: `@"this is a very long string"` takes up just as much memory as `nil`, when assigned to the variable. They are both just a memory address. Of course, the string will be stored somewhere in your memory but it can be re-used by pretty much all your code.

Comment: That really is a fun fact. Still, what concerns me it's the part that I need to declare the variable before being able to use it in the if/else structure. So I take it it's ok to declare it as nil or whatever, and then give it a correct value later?

Comment: The contents of a pointer will always be 4 bytes (or 8 on a 64 bit architecture). Assigning an initial value will write these 4 bytes, and immediately overwriting it will mean you've written 8 bytes. If this is very important to you, simply don't assign an initial value. Make sure to assign it afterwards though, before using it.

Comment: Nah, it's not that kind of application where a couple of bytes really matter. From what I've previously seen, it's important to properly allocate and release your objects in obj-c. In my example, I didn't allocate anything, I set it to nil, something that I usually do when I deallocate a variable. So there lied my concern... I thought that maybe the string would just receive a random pointer, overwriting another object's pointer and leading to a crash, sooner or later